# NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED Heroku App making whole app insecure

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, ssl, heroku

I have an app on Heroku that uses a paid dyno and thus uses their ACM [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management)

This should ensure all traffic between clients and the app are encrypted.

However, my app makes callouts to a separate private API. I'm awaiting a separate self-signed certificate just to be able to connect to this API (so this should all be separate from the Heroku cert). As a temporary workaround..all connections to this API are currently used with

`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';`

I've read about the dangers of this and how to makes all of node unencrypted. My question is if the app is still secure when clients connect to the Heroku instance for other parts of the app not involving the API callouts. Or does setting that env var really make the whole app insecure regardless of the Heroku cert?

Thanks!

Comment: Eh. As with all things security, it's not a yes/no, and more of a gradient. Having `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` does not immediately make your toaster blow up or your app 'insecure'.  It just leaves it vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.  You have what is called 'herd immunity'; that your app among MILLIONS of apps, is unlikely to be targeted for hacking.  We in the security community love that you want to do it right, but understand that leaving that setting on for a few days while you get a valid certificate is not going to collapse society as we know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have both incoming and outgoing connections, and your **outbound** connections to the API are using `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED`.

```
Clients --in--> Your Application --out--> API
```

Your clients connection **inbound** to your application will still be GREEN and secure, but your outbound connections to the API will still be vulnerable.

Much like a chain, it is only as strong as its weakest link.  So if someone were to attack your outbound connection to the API, they could receive all the datas.

You have two methods of solving this:

1. Get a "real" certificate for the API.
2. "Pre-authorize" the self-signed API certificate.

You can download the public key of the self-signed certificate and store it in your NodeJS app. Then, in your request, just add:

```
ca: [fs.readFileSync([certificate path], {encoding: 'utf-8'})]
```

This solution allows you to specify the CA certificate that you EXPECT. Make sure that the common name of the certificate is identical to the address you called in the request (as specified in the host):

```
var req = https.request({ 
      host: '192.168.1.1', 
      port: 443,
      path: '/',
      ca: [fs.readFileSync([certificate path], {encoding: 'utf-8'})],
      method: 'GET',
      rejectUnauthorized: true,
      requestCert: true,
      agent: false
    },
```

This method is MUCH more secure than just blindly setting "Accept all unknown people."  This way is saying "John isn't certified, but I know John, and that's John. Just accept John."

Comment: Self-signed certificates are not inherently bad or evil, they are just misunderstood and misused.  The "self-signed" part just means it did not come from a known-validated third party. But if there are only two parties in this connection (your app, your API), you don't need a third party to validate you. In fact, this is arguably MORE secure because you are telling your app to ONLY validate that ONE specific certificate, not accept all "valid" certificates from a third-party.  Rather than saying, "I'll accept anyone validated", you are now saying "I'll only accept John."